# Handle Multiselect in ListView (WPF + MVVM)

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mvvm

I implemented the following method to handle multi selection on WPF ListView in MVVM (Binding) pattern.

Unfortunately I noticed that for small number of selection (<10 items) it works, but after that it somehow breaks! And not all items IsSelected gets updated!! I'm guessing this is maybe some overflow of the parser.

Any help would be appreciated.

1) In the data type for the ListViewItem I place a Selected/IsSelected property.

```
public class LVItem
{
    // ... properties
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
}
```

2) In the XAML I bind ListViewItem IsSelected property to this LVItem property

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
       <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Selected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
   ...
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

I ofcourse bind the ItemsSource of the ListView to an ObservableCollection of LVItems.

3) When performing an action/command - I iterate the items, check if item.Selected == true, and if so perform the action.

Again, running on debugger clearly shows if I choose too much (ctrl+a on a long list) only some of the items.Selected will be equal to true. Others not...

Comment: For a working two-way Binding you need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged for the LVItem.Selected property. Also note that the ListViewItem.IsSelected property binds two-way by default. No need to set Mode=TwoWay.

Comment: @clemens I forgot to mention I'm using Fody.PropertyChanged - so this is implemented automatically

Comment: Ctr+a doesn't work because of virtualization, i.e. not all items are `ListBoxItems`, so trigger won't work for them.

Comment: In exactly same situation I am using `SelectionChanged` event, which has arguments with `AddedItems` and `RemovedItems`, which you can use to synchronize ViewModel. This way I can keep virtualization on. Perhaps there is a better way.

Comment: yes, you're right it's the same problem, and that solution helps. But I don't really understand what caused the problem and what fixed it. What is this virtualization you speak of ?